# Expectations in sequences

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to get my head around this problem, and I think I have a way to think about it.

So let's say I have $a$ white balls and $b$ black balls in a bag initially. I take out a ball and if it's white, I put it back and if it's black, I replace that black ball with a white ball. Let $M_n$ be the expectation of the number of white balls in the bag after $n$ moves.

I want to show

$$M_{n+1} = \left(1-\frac1{a+b}\right)M_n + 1$$

I think a way to do this problem is by writing something like this

Let $w_n =$ number of white balls after $n$ goes.
Let $b_n =$ number of black balls after $n$ goes.

$$M_{n+1} = P(\text{Pick a WhiteBall})(w_n) + P(\text{Pick a BlackBall})(b_n)$$

But I'm not sure where to go from here. In other words, how do I go from probabilities to expectations in a sequence problem such as this?

Comment: Don’t you mean that the probability of getting a white ball on the $(n+1)$-st go is $\dfrac{w_n}{w_n+b_n}=\dfrac{w_n}{a+b}$?

Comment: oh wait, I think the question changed when you edited it - that should be expectation - here let me change it again

Comment: also, why does that probability make sense?

Comment: Is $M1$ supposed to be $M_1$? If so, why do you have $w_n$ and $b_n$ on the righthand side? In any case, the probability of drawing a white ball isn’t a constant: it depends on the state of the bag, so I don’t understand what you mean by $P(\text{WhiteBall})$ and $P(\text{BlackBall})$.

Comment: ohhh I see what you're saying - ok then that was a mistake in my thinking - I think it should be Mn+1 = ... , as it is shown now, sorry about that - I was thinking about the expectation wrong and for some stupid reason assumed the probability of picking a white ball would stay constant

Comment: Note that on the $(n+1)$-st go the probability of picking a white ball is the fraction that I gave in my first comment above, and the probability of picking a black ball is similarly $\dfrac{b_n}{a+b}$.

Comment: see- I don't see that, because a and b refer to the white and black balls initially in the bag? So shouldn't the probability of picking white on the n+1st have a numerator of the number of white and black balls at n?

Comment: The total number of balls in the bag remains constant, so $w_n+b_n=a+b$.

Comment: ohhh I see that

Comment: but we're still faced with the problem of introducing Mn

Comment: I have a question about the problem... what is the distribution of W(n+1), given that Wn=k?

Answer (score 1):

The key observation here is that the total number of balls is constant. Then, reasoning with elementary probabilities, we have $M_0 = a$ and from then on recursively

$$ M_{n+1} = \frac{M_n}{a+b} M_n + \left( 1 - \frac{M_n}{a+b} \right) (M_n + 1)$$
or
$$ M_{n+1} = \frac{M_n}{a+b} M_n + (M_n + 1) - \frac{M_n}{a+b} M_n - \frac{M_n}{a+b} 
= M_n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{a+b} \right) + 1,$$
as claimed.

Using mathematical induction we can prove that in fact
$$M_n = a+b-b \left( 1- \frac{1}{a+b} \right) ^{n}.$$